# Why is my Intellisense gone on Javascript files in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense, indentation

**UPDATE:**

Apparently the commit thing wasn't actually the issue, because now the problem is back, and everything is checked in. This is so frustrating. It seemed to happen out of nowhere. I literally just ran the project, and then when I next tried to edit the file, got this crap again...

**Original Question**

Everything about intellisense, auto-complete, auto indentation, etc. is gone in my .js files. Like when I hit enter, it just goes to a new line with no indentation at all. I've tried repairing VS, deleting the .vs folder in my solution, and looking through all the intellisense options that I could find.

[image: New lines not keeping indentation]

And it's only javascript files. My C# files work fine.

Has anyone run into this before???

Comment: Does this happen on a new project? Also is this VScode on Mac?

Comment: Nevermind...I have no clue why this was an issue. But I literally just checked in some local commits and it fixed itself.

Answer (score 0):

I hate my life.

I checked in some outstanding commits and the problem went away. I have no clue why source control would have any effect on intellisense and the like, but whatever.

**Update**

This fix was apparently a fluke. See updated question.

Comment: And of course I spent over two hours trying to figure out what the heck is going on before posting on here, and I literally tried this about 30 seconds after I posted.

Comment: so glad to hear that your issue was gone, please mark your reply as an answer and this just a reminder :)

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT Sorry, I was going to, but it wouldn't let me do it right away. :P And then I forgot about it.